# Prestashop - How to add inline script?

Tags: javascript, php, addition, inline, prestashop

I would like to know how to add JS inline in the  of my website by the PHP file of my module. I tried the method "addJS" from the main controler but it seems that this is only works for importing external JS file.

Do you know how I can do to add my script in the head from the "hookDisplayRightColumn" function ?

Thank you in advance for your help and have a nice day!

Mickaël

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't. If you need to add something to header, then you need to call `hookDisplayHeader`.

I assume that you want to add some variables for your script; For that puropose I can suggest `Media:addJsDef()` and `$this->context->controller->addJS()`. Howeverm `Media:addJsDef()` is only avaiable on PrestaShop 1.6 or later; If you need to define some JS variables in your page on PrestaShop 1.5 or lower, you indeed need to use `hookDisplayHeader`.

EDIT:
You may also try to insert your script using hookDisplayRightColumn and then write a block of script to header (not sure if that would work though, also very bad practice).